# comparing values of 2 columns from same pandas dataframe & returning value of 3rd column based on comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare values between 2 columns in the same pandas dataframe and for where ever the match has been found I want to return the values from that row but from a 3rd column.

Basically if the following is dataframe `df`

```
| date      | date_new   | category | value  |
| --------- | ---------- | -------- | ------ |
|2016-05-11 | 2018-05-15 | day      | 1000.0 |
|2020-03-28 | 2018-05-11 | night    | 2220.1 |
|2018-05-15 | 2020-03-28 | day      | 142.8  |
|2018-05-11 | 2019-01-29 | night    | 1832.9 |
```

I want to add a new column say, `value_new` which is basically obtained by getting the values from `value` after comparing for every date value in `date_new` for every date value in `date` followed by comparing if both the rows have same `category` values.

**[steps of transformation]**
- 1. for each value in `date_new` look for a match in `date`
- 2. if match found, compare if values in `category` column also match
- 3. if both the matches in above steps fulfilled, pick the corresponding value from `value` column from the row where both the matches fulfilled, otherwise leave blank.

So, I would finally want the final dataframe to look something like this.

```
| date      | date_new   | category | value  | value_new |
| --------- | ---------- | -------- | ------ | --------- |
|2016-05-11 | 2018-05-15 | day      | 1000.0 | 142.8     |
|2020-03-28 | 2018-05-11 | night    | 2220.1 | 1832.9    |
|2018-05-15 | 2020-03-28 | day      | 142.8  | None      |
|2018-05-11 | 2016-05-11 | day      | 1832.9 | 1000.0    |
```

Comment: Can you show a sample calculation?

Comment: Also, what if there are multiple matches?

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa at any point `date_new` and `category` together won't have any duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and assigned new column:

```
df['value_new'] = df.merge(df, 
                           left_on=['date_new','category'], 
                           right_on=['date','category'], how='left')['value_y']
print (df)

         date    date_new category   value  value_new
0  2016-05-11  2018-05-15      day  1000.0      142.8
1  2020-03-28  2018-05-11    night  2220.1        NaN
2  2018-05-15  2020-03-28      day   142.8        NaN
3  2018-05-11  2016-05-11      day  1832.9     1000.0
```

Comment: wow that was so simple! thanks :) Just one question, is that a typo in your submitted solution or does it really has to be `value_y` and not simply `value` as that's the original col name?

Comment: I see that if I keep the original col name `value` it throws an error, so it seems i do need to mention it as `value_y` but I don't understand the reason ?? `value_y` never even existed, can you please explain why it only works with `value_y` and not `value` ?

Comment: @AmanSingh - Because `merge` by same DataFrame pandas processing `value` with appending suffix, so need `value_y`

Comment: i think i now understand the behavior of pandas upon merging by itself, thank you :)